# Please help to debug this [snuffleupagus][disabled_function]

Tags: php, wordpress

[snuffleupagus][disabled_function] Aborted execution on call of the function 'curl_setopt', because its argument '$option' content (81) matched the rule 'Please don't turn CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST off.' in /home/glodarac/public_html/wp-includes/Requests/Transport/cURL.php on line 150

Comment: I suggest not trying to turn SSL verification off in your curl options, just like the error message says

Answer (score 1):

snuffleupagus is a hardening module for PHP 7.x

It detected that your PHP program, "cURL.php", turned off SSL host verification and stopped the program from running.

I suggest you log a call to your Wordpress plugin provider to update the code to follow security principals and not disable SSL security checks.

The incorrect way to fix this is to ask your hosting provider to disable the snuffleupagus
security checks.